# 422 Unprocessable Entity in Quickblox Signup/login in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox

I am an iOS developer & currently trying to develop a chat app using Quickblox in iOS. I have dowloaded sample from Quickblox. App is running fine When I am running USERS sample on iPhone (iOS 8.1) but when I am trying to run on iPad (iOS 8.1.2), getting 422 unprocessable entity error. I am getting this error while login & Signup process in sample.

Could any one please assist me in resolving this error or any idea/link would be great? Please Also let me know if there any other input required from my end.

Comment: Please provide Xcode logs

Answer (score 2):

**422 unprocessable entity** means a validation error. The backend usually returns **422** status in a case when user's input data is wrong.

Can you check you Xcode logs, there should be a human readable explanation what is wrong.

Comment: Yes I faced this issue in iPad (iOS8.1.2) only. Everything is working fine in iOS 8 & iOS 9.2 iPad device. Looks like some device specific issue at my end.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS are you able to provide logs form that device?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko I am facing same issue when doing social media login , I have visited many links regarding this but no luck ,please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824994/bad-authentication-data-quickblox-android